# Send image through C socket

Tags: c, image, sockets

```
void callback (struct Request req) {

    char buffer[8196];
    int file;
    bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

    if(!strncmp(req.method, "GET", 3)){

        if (!strcmp(req.path, "/")){

            memcpy(buffer, "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n", 44);
            response(buffer);

            int file = open("./static/index.html", O_RDONLY);
            long ret;

            while ((ret = read(file, buffer, 8196)) > 0) {
                response(buffer);   
            }

        }else if (!strcmp(req.path, "/login")){

            memcpy(buffer, "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n", 44);
            response(buffer);

            int file = open("./static/login.html", O_RDONLY);
            long ret;

            while ((ret = read(file, buffer, 8196)) > 0) {
                response(buffer);   
            }

        }else{

            char path[80];
            char header[240];

            sprintf(path, "./static%s", req.path);
            int ext = readFile(path, buffer);
            char type[15];
            struct stat st;

            if(!ext){
                strcpy(type, "text/html\0");
            }else if(ext == 1){
                strcpy(type, "text/javascript\0");
            }else if(ext == 2){
                strcpy(type, "text/css\0");
            }else if(ext == 3){
                strcpy(type, "image/jpeg\0");
            }

            stat(path, &st);
            sprintf(header, "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: %s\r\nContent-Length: %lld\r\n\r\n", type, st.st_size);
            response(header);

            int file = open(path, O_RDONLY);
            long ret;

            while ((ret = read(file, buffer, 8196)) > 0) {
                buffer[8196-1] = 0;
                response(buffer);   
            }

        }

    }else if(!strncmp(req.method, "POST", 4)){

    }

    bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

};

void response (char message[]) {
    write(clientsocket, message, strlen(message));
};
```

This is the code I have for my HTTP server coded in C. The callback function is executed everytime the socket receives a request. The struct Request has 2 `char []`, method that can be `POST` or `GET`, and path, which contains the request's path. The server sends properly the static files such html, js and css files. It serves the bootstrap statics properly, although if `buffer[8196-1] = 0;` is not when I send the file, the file contains wrong characters.

I try to send a `.jpg` image, and the headers are properly sended, but the file is not. When I access to `127.0.0.1:8080/image.jpg`, Firefox displays an error that the image contains errors and can't be displayed, or just display a bunch of caracters and the server stops serving the rest of js and css files.

I read all the questions releated to this and I didn't file a solution jet. The image size is 1'1Mb, maybe is that the problem? I think not because I send the data in 'pieces', but I'm not sure at all. The program doesn't show me an error about the file, seems to be opened and read correctly.

It's a header problem maybe? The rest of the js and css files are sended in the same pice of code that the image (the `else` statement), ad they don't have any trouble, and the FF console show me the headers of every file, and they're correct so I think that's not the problem.

Thank's advanced!

Comment: When requesting `/` or `/login`, you are not sending any `Content-Length` or `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` response header so the receiver knows how to read the body data and how to determine when the data stops. And you should not be doing anything with `buffer[8196-1]` at all.  You should be telling `response()` how many bytes are actuallly in `buffer` and let it send the `buffer` as-is up to that number of bytes.  Don't rely on `strlen()` for binary data, since binary data can contain embedded nulls. And you should be sending an HTTP error if `open()` fails to open the file being requested.

Comment: So do I have to add thouse headers too? I removed the `buffer[8196-1]`, but the JS bootstrap file contains like damage characters every where. In `response`i changed the `strlen()`with the buffer size. And I didn't add the error with the open function because of I know exactly which files are called and what I hace in the server. I mean, all that I request, it's opened and readed properly.

Answer (score 3):

When the client requests either `/` or `/login`, you are not sending any `Content-Length` or `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` response header. Without that, the client can't know whether a message body exists or when to stop reading it, unless you close the socket connection immediately after sending the response (see [RFC 1945 Section 7.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-7.2.2) and [RFC 2616 Section 4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4)).  Which you should be doing anyway since you are sending an HTTP 1.0 response without a `Connection: keep-alive` response header.

You should not be doing anything with `buffer[8196-1]` at all.  You should be telling `response()` how many bytes are actually in `buffer` and let it send the `buffer` as-is up to that number of bytes.  Don't rely on `strlen()` for binary data, since binary data can contain embedded nulls.

You should be sending an HTTP error if `open()` fails to open the file being requested.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```
void callback (struct Request req)
{
    char buffer[8196];
    int file;
    bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

    if (strncmp(req.method, "GET") == 0)
    {
        char path[258];
        char header[240];
        char *type;

        if (strcmp(req.path, "/") == 0)
        {
            strcpy(path, "./static/index.html");
            type = "text/html";
        }
        else if (strcmp(req.path, "/login") == 0)
        {
            strcpy(path, "./static/login.html");
            type = "text/html";
        }
        else
        {
            sprintf(path, "./static%.258s", req.path);
            // or: snprintf(path, 258, "./static%s", req.path); 

            int ext = determineFileType(path);
            switch (ext)
            {
                case 0: // HTML
                    type = "text/html";
                    break;
                case 1: // Javascript
                    type = "text/javascript";
                    break;
                case 2: // CSS
                    type = "text/css";
                    break;
                case 3: // JPG
                    type = "image/jpeg";
                    break;
                default: // something else
                    type = "application/octet-stream";
                    break;
            }
        }

        int file = open(path, O_RDONLY);
        if (file == -1)
        {
            // send different errors depending on the failure, like 404 if the file is not found, etc...
            if (errno == ENOENT) {
                strcpy(header, "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n");
            } else {
                strcpy(header, "HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Error\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n");
            }
            response(header, strlen(header));
        }
        else
        {
            struct stat st;
            stat(path, &st);

            sprintf(header, "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: %s\r\nContent-Length: %lld\r\n\r\n", type, st.st_size);
            response(header, strlen(header));   

            long ret;
            while ((ret = read(file, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0)
                response(buffer, ret);   

            close(file);
        }
    }
    else if (strncmp(req.method, "POST") == 0)
    {
        //...
    }
}

void response (void *message, int msglen)
{
    char *msg = (char*) message;

    while (msglen > 0)
    {
         int len = write(clientsocket, msg, msglen);
         if (len <= 0) return;
         msg += len;
         msglen -= len;
    }
}
```

Comment: I visited this page because I was having an error sending CSS over my C server. I didn't realize I had to specify `text/css`. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `write()` in `response()` does not necessarily write the complete buffer to the socket.

If there is already to much data buffered by the OS it might only write a part of the data in the buffer and you will need another (or several more) calls to `write()` to get everything transmitted. To see how much data was transmitted look at the return value of`write()`. It returns the number that were written.

Additionally you use `strlen()` to determine the length of the data to transmit, but images are not strings. They can contain zero bytes and `strlen()` will not give useful results. Better pass the length of the data explicitly to the `response()` function.

Also, when reading the image file, `buffer[8196-1] = 0` will overwrite bytes of the image with zeros.

Comment: I think that the `write`problem is solved with the while loop, which is just in the `else` statement.

Comment: It is not enough to call `response() in a loop. You have to call `write()` itself in a loop as well, in case it writes fewer bytes then you requested.

Answer (score 2):

[HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) is a complex protocol (the specifications have hundreds of pages). So better use some existing libraries for it.
On the server side (to embed some web server in your application), use e.g. [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/).
On the client side (to make HTTP requests in your application), use e.g. [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)

BTW, you probably could [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) your program to understand the really executed [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

Comment: I did this for learning, that's why I'm coding it from scratch.